# WooCommerce change password form on another page

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, templates, woocommerce

Using the latest version of WooCommerce, I'm trying to get the change password form to show up on different pages. The problem is, copying the default form from woocommerce > templates > myaccount > form-edit-account.php and placing the code on another page would not work.

This is original code from that template:

```
<?php


if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
exit;
}

do_action( 'woocommerce_before_edit_account_form' ); ?>

<form class="woocommerce-EditAccountForm edit-account" action="" 
method="post">

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_edit_account_form_start' ); ?>

<p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--first form-row form-
row-first">
    <label for="account_first_name"><?php _e( 'First name', 'woocommerce' ); 
?> <span class="required">*</span></label>
    <input type="text" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text 
input-text" name="account_first_name" id="account_first_name" value="<?php 
echo esc_attr( $user->first_name ); ?>" />
</p>
<p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--last form-row form-row-
last">
    <label for="account_last_name"><?php _e( 'Last name', 'woocommerce' ); ?
> <span class="required">*</span></label>
    <input type="text" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text 
 input-text" name="account_last_name" id="account_last_name" value="<?php 
 echo esc_attr( $user->last_name ); ?>" />
</p>
<div class="clear"></div>

<p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-
 wide">
    <label for="account_email"><?php _e( 'Email address', 'woocommerce' ); ?
 > <span class="required">*</span></label>
    <input type="email" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--email 
 input-text" name="account_email" id="account_email" value="<?php echo 
 esc_attr( $user->user_email ); ?>" />
</p>

<!--<fieldset>
    <legend><?php _e( 'Password change', 'woocommerce' ); ?></legend>

    <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-
 row-wide">
        <label for="password_current"><?php _e( 'Current password (leave 
 blank to leave unchanged)', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label>
        <input type="password" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--
  password input-text" name="password_current" id="password_current" />
    </p>
    <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-
  row-wide">
        <label for="password_1"><?php _e( 'New password (leave blank to leave unchanged)', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label>
        <input type="password" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--
   password input-text" name="password_1" id="password_1" />
    </p>
    <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
        <label for="password_2"><?php _e( 'Confirm new password', 
 'woocommerce' ); ?></label>
        <input type="password" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--
  password input-text" name="password_2" id="password_2" />
    </p>
</fieldset>-->
<div class="clear"></div>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_edit_account_form' ); ?>

<p>
    <?php wp_nonce_field( 'save_account_details' ); ?>
    <input type="submit" class="woocommerce-Button button" name="save_account_details" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Save changes', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="save_account_details" />
</p>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_edit_account_form_end' ); ?>
```

So my question is how to show only this code content in separated page:

```
<legend><?php _e( 'Password change', 'woocommerce' ); ?></legend>

    <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-
row-wide">
        <label for="password_current"><?php _e( 'Current password (leave 
blank to leave unchanged)', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label>
        <input type="password" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--
 password input-text" name="password_current" id="password_current" />
    </p>
    <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-
 row-wide">
        <label for="password_1"><?php _e( 'New password (leave blank to 
 leave unchanged)', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label>
        <input type="password" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--
 password input-text" name="password_1" id="password_1" />
    </p>
    <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-
 row-wide">
        <label for="password_2"><?php _e( 'Confirm new password', 
 'woocommerce' ); ?></label>
        <input type="password" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--
 password input-text" name="password_2" id="password_2" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
```

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

If I were to do this, I would carefully pluck out that form and then just drop it on another custom page template in a sidebar or something, and then use that template for the pages where you want it to show.

The thing is, as is often with Woo, sometimes whenever WordPress runs the Woo actions, e.g. `<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_edit_account_form_start' ); ?>`, it might be pulling HTML that helps the layout, or even loading in Javascript in some weird cases. You will want to pull in ALL that "excess" form information, get it functional, and then ween out the pieces that you can while keeping the functionality in tact.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Yes that halps but when press to save New password, data is not updated into DB.

Comment: Look at the POST request that is being sent out in Developers' Tools and see what the response is. If it's erroring you can debug and get to the bottom of why it's broken.